# SCIP installation produce broken link

Tags: linux, scip

I am trying to install the SCIP optimization suite on linux MINT 17 QIANA. I have downloaded scipoptsuite-3.1.0 form http://scip.zib.de/ and ran the make command with ZIMPL=false option.
The result of the make process was

```
** Build complete.
** Find your SCIP binary in "/home/patstop/Downloads/scipoptsuite-3.1.0/scip-3.1.0/bin".
** Enter "make test" to solve a number of easy instances in order to verify that SCIP runs correctly.
```

However the test will fail because it will not find the scip bin file, in fact the link in the above mentioned directory is broken.
I don't really understand why that is happening, I did succesfully installed the package a couple of days ago in Ubuntu, and I don't recall any problem in the process. Can someone give me any clue of what am I missing?

*edit*

This is the error message:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/patstop/Downloads/scipoptsuite-3.1.0/scip-3.1.0'
cd check; \
bash ./check.sh short bin/scip-3.1.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx default    scip-3.1.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx 3600 2100000000 6144 1 default 10000 false false 3.1.0 spx false /tmp optimize;
Skipping test since the binary bin/scip-3.1.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx does not exist.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/patstop/Downloads/scipoptsuite-3.1.0/scip-3.1.0'
```

I ran the command from the same directory in which a ran the `make` command (I did try to ran it from `scip-3.1.0` dir but the result was the same).
This is the result of `ls -l` in the bin directory (links are shown in red):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Aug 25 19:26 scip -> scip-3.1.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Aug 25 19:26 scip.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx -> scip-3.1.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx
```

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error message when you run `make test` and the directory from where you execute this command? Can you also paste the broken link?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I edited the initial post with the additional information

Comment: Looks to me like the check.sh script is broken. The script is executed from the check-subdirectory of the SCIP root, so it shouldn't look for bin/... but rather ../bin/... I.e. go one directory up. This is strange since we are working with that every day.

Comment: What is the exact content of the bin-directory?

Comment: The real binary is missing. I would try `make` clean first, then make SCIP again.

Comment: In the bin directory there are only those two links: scip and scip.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx
It seems to me weird that scip.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx is a link to himself. Can that somehow be the problem?

Comment: Not exactly to itself: the link name has no version 3.1.0 in its name, but the binary would. Have you tried `make clean`?

Comment: Then try `make ZIMPL=false` again from inside the scip-directory.

Comment: I have done `make clean` and `make`, but I had the same result as before

Comment: ok if I ran from inside the scip directory with `make ZIMPL=false` it will fail with the message
    `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsoplex.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt
     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go. SCIP needs a working SoPlex installation (or some other of the supported LP solvers listed [here](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/MAKE.php))  as prerequisite. That SoPlex could not be successfully built might be because of the ncurses-library reported missing.

Please make sure you have these libraries (ncurses etc.) installed as developer versions.
Then go to the SoPlex-directory, and type `make`. If you have no more error messages,
change to SCIP, and run `make` here. You probably need to adjust the links to the soplex include directory (spxinc->soplex-2.0/src) and (libsoplex.a -> soplex-2.0/lib/libsoplex.gnu.linux.x86_64.a) inside the lib-subdirectory of SCIP, if it still cannot find the lib after a successful build of SoPlex. You can also do so by running `make links`.

It seems that the Optimization Suite Makefile needs to be revised so that it correctly warns you if a sub-build process was unsuccesful.

Comment: Yes this was the problem! I ran `make` on the SoPlex directory, `sudo atp-get install ncurses*`, and finally `make ZIMPL=false` in the scip directory. Seems like the missing library was necessary only for the very last step of the process. Thank you very much for the support and the Help